# Difference between std::reverse_iterator member functions: _Get_current() and base()?

Tags: c++, casting, iterator, reverse-iterator

Both member functions appear to do the same thing.
In the example below, both return an iterator pointing to the same memory location.

a) Is there any practical difference?

b) Why cant I find any info for `_Get_current()` in the std class documentation? I suspect the underscore prefix is a clue.

```
std::string s = std::string( "A B C" ) ;    

std::string::iterator iter1 = s.begin();
std::string::reverse_iterator iter2 = s.rbegin();

std::string::iterator iter3 = iter2.base();
std::string::iterator iter4 = iter2._Get_current();
```

Comment: `_Get_current` is internal to the implementation. Don't use undocumented things.

Comment: The underscore prefix, followed by a capital letter is indeed a clue.  It is an implementation detail that happens to exist in the `std::reverse_iterator` that _you_ are using.  You should not expect it to exist, nor should you rely on what it does.  It is not for you to use.

Comment: Just out of interest, why would visual studio include internal functions in the class member list thus making it seem like they are part of the interface when the opposite is true?

Comment: @tuk: Because the job of Intellisense is to tell you what the code *says*, not what the code *means*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *ever* see an identifier that starts with an `_` followed by a capital letter, that identifier is being used by the internals of the C++ implementation and should *never* be used by you. You don't see it documented because it's for internal use only, specific to that implementation of the library type.

Just use the actual interface.